# Looking for some information in getting Java to communicate with a website

Tags: java, javascript

I was wondering if one could write a Java application and put it on a website and then have it running so that when a user used your website it could interact with some html/javascript page which would communicate with the Java program.

So basically, the html5 would be used to display the java program but all the logic and everything else would be server side in Java.

I don't want to use a java applet since it requires users getting a security warning and most browsers do not autorun a java application. I just think it would look cleaner and work nicer.

Does anyone know anything about this and could give me a little abstract just to point me in the right direction so I can learn more?

Thanks

Comment: This is called a [web app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application), and Java would be used on the server to respond on port 80 (8080, 443, etc., maybe using [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)). Note, this is done all the time; [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview), for instance, is a Java-based web app with an HTML/JS frontend (for the most part).

Comment: Okay this is what I'm looking for. I just wanted to make sure doing something like this is kosher and there's not some far better way.

Comment: Building a Java-based web app can be a bit more sophisticated than using something like a [LAMP stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29), Ruby, even Python. I usually wouldn't consider it for a small, standalone project unless you already have an environment available and have a decent feel for Java. It depends, but there's lots of options, Java (in my opinion) not necessarily the best for many small web app projects.

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebApp.html), plus an [index of Java EE tutorials](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/tutorials-137605.html).

Comment: *"java applet .. requires users getting a security warning"*  No it doesn't.  You are thinking of a ***trusted*** applet.  *"most browsers do not autorun a java application"* Chrome seems to be difficult about it.  Name another browser.  (Note that browsers might come with no JRE, that is what [deployJava.js](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) is for.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat difficult to tell from your question but you might find GWT useful. You code everything in Java, and the client-side portion gets compiled into html/javascript which communicates to the server portion with AJAX. http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start by developing a simple Java web app using html, jsp and servlet. Try the Google App Engine for deployment as it is free for hosting.

http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/simple-servlet-example.html